# There was a recoverable, provider-specific error, such as an RPC failure. SQL to MySQL linked server no longer working

Tags: sql-server, mysql, linked-server

I have been searching all day and trying every manner of solution that I come across, yet nothing has resolved this issue.

Here is my was working code:

```
delete RemoteTable from OPENQUERY (LIGHTSAIL, 'SELECT * FROM rm00102_TEST') RemoteTable JOIN (SELECT B.*--, 'MODIFIED'  AS 'CHANGE_TYPE' FROM (
        SELECT * FROM [OFI].[dbo].[RM00102] WHERE [CUSTNMBR] <> '54322' AND [CUSTNMBR] <> '54321'
        EXCEPT
        SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (LIGHTSAIL, 'SELECT * FROM rm00102_TEST') 
    ) S1 INNER JOIN OPENQUERY (LIGHTSAIL, 'SELECT * FROM rm00102_TEST') B ON S1.DEX_ROW_ID = B.DEX_ROW_ID ) LocalTable on RemoteTable.DEX_ROW_ID = LocalTable.DEX_ROW_ID GO
```

All I get now is an error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LIGHTSAIL" returned
> message "Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status
> value.". Msg 7345, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 The OLE DB provider
> "MSDASQL" for linked server "LIGHTSAIL" could not delete from table
> "SELECT * FROM production_live.UPR00102". There was a recoverable,
> provider-specific error, such as an RPC failure.
>
> Completion time: 2023-09-29T16:07:32.9815969-05:00

I have found many answers and tried many of the solutions, but the issue remains.
Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!